# Анимация установки текста в TextView

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Есть `TextView` в котором я хочу отобразить массив чисел по-очереди. Попробовал этот [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8239495/5634351) но по-моему он мне не совсем подходит. Хочу это сделать с помощью  `ObjectAnimator`, подобным образом:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_learn_result);

    tvCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_count);


    int[] array = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    ObjectAnimator animator = new ObjectAnimator();
    animator.ofInt(tvCount, "progress" ,array);
    animator.setDuration(6000);
    animator.start();
}
```

Но получаю:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                             at android.animation.ValueAnimator.initAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:534)
                                                                             at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.initAnimation(ObjectAnimator.java:880)
                                                                             at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:610)
                                                                             at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:589)
                                                                             at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1106)
                                                                             at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1117)
                                                                             at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
                                                                             at com.attrakti.englishfor.activities.MyActivity.onCreate(LearnActivityResult.java:59)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: покажите полный стактрейс, и больше кода - конкретно, где вы инициализируете `tvCount`

Comment: @metalurgus есть

Comment: Ну, вы нигде не инициализируете `tvCount`. В итоге он у вас null

Comment: пардон, я просто лишнее убирал с кода, tvCount проинициализировал. проблема таже. Скажите  а так вобще можно делать? Может я неправельное имя сеттера указываю?

Comment: Вы так и не показали, что такое `tvCount`, и как и когда его инициализируете.

Comment: @metalurgus изменил вопрос, tvCount - это обычное TextView

Comment: как минимум, вы пытаетесь анимировать у `TextView` свойство `progress`, но с чего вы взяли, что это свойство есть у `TextView`?

Comment: так вот, я ж об этом, там по-идеии должно быть другой свойство, вот какое?

Comment: с ObjectAnimator вообще будет труднее, чем просто через интервал времени выставлять новую цифру в TextView. Сделайте просто через `Handler.postDelayed`

Comment: Да, пожалуй так и сделаю, просто с ObjectAnimator вариант мне был больше по душе. Что бы через ObjectAnimator сделать - я так понимаю надо свою вьюху уже делать, да?

Comment: не вьюху, но переопределять анимацию, что 100% будет сложнее.

Comment: может подскажите где можно посмотреть как это делаеться, мне все же интересно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте через `ValueAnimator`:

```
    final TextView tvCount  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_count);

    int[] array = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(array);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            tvCount.setText(""+animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    animator.setDuration(6000);
    animator.start();
```

Comment: отлично, то что нужно!